# Fetch list of forms that are belong to a specific student

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a class of `Form` and `Student`. A student may have 0 or many forms. I set the relation between them as `OneToMany`. Now, I need to fetch the forms that are owned by a specific student. I have two questions at that point. How should I fetch those forms in the URL? Let's say I want to fetch the forms of the student with id=7.

*Option 1:*

```
api/v1/forms?studentId=7
```

*Option 2:*

```
api/v1/students/7/forms
```

Which one of them is most used or more reasonable?
The second problem is that. Normally, when I want to add a new method to the `JpaRepo`. I just need to add the method that is served by Jpa such that `findAll`, `findByStudentId`. Since I have a list of forms in the Student entity/model. How can I fetch all the forms? Which named method should I use? To sum up, I need to know whether I should write the method in `FormDataAccess` or `StudentDataAccess`. And what should be the method name?

### Student

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Student_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Course_id")
    private int courseID;
    @Column(name="Oasis_id")
    private Long oasisID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Form> forms;
}
```

### Form Model

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="form")
public class Form {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Student_id", nullable = false)
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Attending_id", nullable = false)
    private AttendingPhysician attending;
    @Column(name = "Kayit_no", nullable = false)
    private String kayitNo;

    @Column(name = "Staj_turu", nullable = false)
    private String stajTuru;

    @Column(name = "Yas", nullable = false)
    private int yas;

    @Column(name = "Cinsiyet", nullable = false)
    private String cinsiyet;

    @Column(name = "Sikayet", nullable = false)
    private String sikayet;

    @Column(name = "Ayirici_tani", nullable = false)
    private String ayiriciTani;

    @Column(name = "Kesin_tani", nullable = false)
    private String kesinTani;

    @Column(name = "Tedavi_yontemi", nullable = false)
    private String tedaviYontemi;

    @Column(name = "Etkilesim_turu", nullable = false)
    private String etkilesimTuru;

    @Column(name = "Kapsam", nullable = false)
    private String kapsam;

    @Column(name = "Gerceklestigi_ortam", nullable = false)
    private String gerceklestigiOrtam;

    @Column(name = "Status", nullable = false)
    private String status;

    @Column(name="Date_sent", nullable = false)  // Convert to timestamp using java Date @CreationTimestamp, @UpdateTimestamp
    private String dateSent;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really simple.

I just need to write a query in my `FormDataAccess`.

```
@Query(" from Form where student.id = :studentId")
List<Form> findFormByStudentId(int studentId);
```

now I can retrieve the forms using this path

```
api/v1/forms/student/7
```

I still wonder how to retrieve the forms from the Student side, not Form side such that

```
api/v1/student/7/forms
```